# hard fault inv state part 2

Tags: c++, embedded, stm32, keil

I am unsure how to debug this error. I am getting a hard fault exception that is taking me to an infinite loop for my stm32 eval2 board when I try to use the camera. I think that I am supposed to look at the registers for this problem, but I am unsure of what exactly to look for in the registers. I will post them here, I suppose, in case they are helpful for debugging. Also I am using keil and coding in c++.

```
R0    =   0x20029500
R1    =   0x00000000
R2    =   0x2002AE10
R3    =   0x000006A0
R4    =   0x00000FB4
R5    =   0x3FE8F5C3
R6    =   0x00000800
R7    =   0x20029C84
R8    =   0x2002917C
R9    =   0x00000001
R10   =   0x00000001
R11   =   0x0000001A
R12   =   0x20029180
R13(SP) = 0x2002B890
R14(LR) = 0xFFFFFFFD
R15(PC) = 0x080171C6
xPSR  =   0x01000003
```

[image: SCB screenshot]

[image: SCB screenshot part 2]

BFAR: 0x10001100
CFSR: 0x00000000
HFSR: 0x00000000
DFSR: 0x00000000
AFSR: 0x00000000

Comment: possible duplicate of [hard fault inv state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904615/hard-fault-inv-state)

Comment: Again, look at my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22423647/1382251, and post the values of these registers properly. Indicate the name and value of each register. The entire memory contents of whatever comes after it is irrelevant in the context of this question.

Comment: Publish the following: BFAR (at 0xE000ED38), CFSR (at 0xE000ED28), HFSR (at 0xE000ED2C), DFSR (at 0xE000ED30), AFSR (at 0xE000ED3C).

Comment: If you're still having problems on how to investigate the hard-fault after referring to http://www.keil.com/appnotes/files/apnt209.pdf (which explains it explains in great details), then please let me and others on this forum know.

Comment: @Ross: The other post was voted to close. I suggested OP (on the other post) a few ways to investigate it, and if unsuccessful, then to publish a few more relevant details and ask it again (since it can no longer be answered there).

Comment: ok i think i posted them properly @barakmanos

Comment: If you put a memory-window image, then at least set it to a column of 4 bytes before you copy-paste it. It's impossible to foillow addresses and register values this way!!!

Comment: In addition, the value at 0xE000ED38 doesn't look like the value that you specified for BFAR. Are you sure that the information you provided is accurate? Otherwise, trying to understand the scenario is useless.

Comment: @barakmanos my apologies I don´t know how I messed that up. I fixed it.

Comment: You fixed what??? There are still 5 bytes on each line, and the value at 0xE000ED38 doesn't look like the value that you specified for BFAR!!!

Comment: I thought you just wanted the values of those registers.